# ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, noclassdeffounderror

I am getting the following error while running the following code in the sql developer:

**creating java source code-**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED demoskr1 AS
package ScreenShot;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;

class demoskr1
{
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
  try{      
                            Thread.sleep(5000);
                            Robot awt_robot = new Robot();
                            String path = "C:\\Users\\pbafna\\workspace\\shot.jpg"; 
                            BufferedImage Entire_Screen = awt_robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
                            ImageIO.write(Entire_Screen, "jpg", new File(path));
                            System.out.println("Screenshot saved");
 }
  catch (Exception e) {
              System.out.println("Something went wrong.");
                  }   
  }
  };
```

**Creating a procedure-**

```
create or replace procedure proc_capture 
as 
 language Java 
 name 'demoskr1.main(java.lang.String[])';
```

**Running the procedure-**

```
 begin
  proc_capture();
  end;
```

After running this I am getting the following error:

```
ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
ORA-06512: at "XXOSC.PROC_CAPTURE", line 1
ORA-06512: at line 2
29532. 00000 -  "Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: %s"
*Cause:    A Java exception or error was signaled and could not be
           resolved by the Java code.
*Action:   Modify Java code, if this behavior is not intended.
```

Comment: Apart from the robot problem: your approach will fail when trying to access the file system. A Java stored procedure accesses the *server* file system (where presumably, your home directory does not exist) and requires special privileges for that.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but can you pls tell me if there is any way I can run this java program using plsql? Or is it not possible?

Answer (score 4):

You are using [`java.awt.Robot`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) which needs a graphical, non-headless environment to work correctly while the database servers doesn't provide it. As per [User Interfaces on the Server](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/jjdev/server-user-interface.html#GUID-D74251C4-2575-411E-9361-8E333D167BA0) Oracle docs:

> Oracle Database furnishes all core Java class libraries on the server, including those associated with presentation of the user interfaces. However, it is inappropriate for code running on the server to attempt to materialize or display a user interface on the server. Users running applications in Oracle JVM environment should not be expected nor allowed to interact with or depend on the display and input hardware of the server where Oracle Database is running.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but can you pls tell me if there is any way I can run this java program using plsql? Or is it not possible?